# webcomponents-lite with ES6 doesn't work in IE 11 and 10

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polymer, web-component

We are using WebComponents with ES6 syntax.

[WebComponents](http://webcomponents.org/) polyfill **webcomponents-lite.js** (which doesn't include ShadowDOM) **is not working in IE 11** whereas the webcomponents.js (which includes ShadowDOM) works fine. For our project use case, we would like to use 'custom-elements' without ShadowDOM.

An error is thrown in IE, if we use webcomponents-lite.js - `SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught.`

Is there any workaround available ?

EDIT: The code which I'm trying to run in IE with [webcomponents-lite.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.7.22/webcomponents-lite.js)

*HTML*: `<super-button></super-button>`

*JS*(ES6 format):

```
class SuperBtn extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
      super();
  }
  createdCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = "Invoke Ultron!";
      this.addEventListener('click', () => alert(this.textContent + ' has been clicked'));
    }
}

document.registerElement("super-button", SuperBtn);
```

Comment: what do you mean by ES6 syntax? You can use Custom Elements without DOM using webcomponents.js anyway.

Comment: yes, I meant `class` notation. It is working with webcomponents.js but not with webcomponents-lite.js

Comment: I have added an issue in webcomponents github repo(in a more refined way). Please have a look - https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/631.

Comment: Ok i see you are using a transpiler. I thought you were using only in-browser JS. Did you try without super or without constructor?

Comment: removing `super()` or `constructor` doesn't help. The `_inherits()` method is added from the transpiler when we use `extends`, which we obviously need for HTMLElement. Here, the HTMLElement is returned as Object instead of function, which is by the way expected by the `_inherits()` method

Comment: @Supersharp  I have raised an issue in babel, may be you would like to have a look ? https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4659

Comment: Sorry i don't use transpiler. i'm not sure opening issues will help. But use of reflect.construct or object.create( HTMLElement.prototype ) could. Anyway you can always use webcomponent.js...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can declare a Custom Element v1 with the original `prototype` notation.

This works with [another polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element) from *Web Reflection*:

```
var CEo = function ()
{
    console.log( "created" )
    return Reflect.construct( HTMLElement, [], CEo )
}

CEo.prototype = Object.create( HTMLElement.prototype )
CEo.prototype.constructor = CEo

CEo.prototype.connectedCallback = function ()
{
    console.log( "connected" )
    this.innerHTML = "Hello v1"
} 

customElements.define( "object-v1", CEo )
```

*Note:* you'll need to use a polyfill like [the one of Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) to get `Reflect.construct` method.